# domain-name.com/user and other URLS not loading

Tags: uri

When I go to my `domain.com/user` I get a blank page, where as usually that was the URL  I go to to log in and change content. I came across this thing: https://www.drupal.org/node/256410, but I do not know if it is the same issue. I tried uploading a new `.htaccess` file to no avail. Any thoughts/ suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable apache's rewrite mod. and then restart your apache server. 
Then, goto configuration and check clean URL. After that your site will be using clean URL.

Comment: How do I enable apache's rewrite mod?

Comment: Depends on your system. For Debian: `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and restart apache. Consult your system administrator to be certain

Comment: Ya agree with @Clive